# Was Turing's team involved in the development of the Ultra system to determine which decrypted Enigma messages to act upon?

Tags: world-war-ii, alan-turing

Did Alan Turing's decryption team develop an statistical analysis algorithm to decide whether to use information from decrypted Enigma messages without risking the Germans to find out that they had broken the code, as depicted in the film The Imitation Game?

I would have thought those decisions were made at a much higher level. [Some sources](http://www.slate.com/blogs/browbeat/2014/12/03/the_imitation_game_fact_vs_fiction_how_true_the_new_movie_is_to_alan_turing.html) claim that the scene in the movie where they decide not to save the brother of one of the members of the team so that the Germans don't suspect that the code has been broken, is fiction. However, there is a scene later where Turing suggests to Menzies (the head of British secret intelligence) that they could develop a method based on statistical analysis to decide when to use the code, only so that they could win the war, but not too much so that the Germans never find out that the code has been broken. The actual meeting between Turing and Menzies probably did not occur, since Turing [did not meet him](http://www.slate.com/blogs/browbeat/2014/12/03/the_imitation_game_fact_vs_fiction_how_true_the_new_movie_is_to_alan_turing.html). But the question remains whether Turing (or any of the codebreakers) ever helped to develop or suggested to develop such a statistical analysis.

[Other sources](http://www.ew.com/article/2014/11/28/fact-checking-the-film-imitation-game) claim that in fact, it was Menzies who came up with Ultra, which was the name given to the system to determine which messages to use. Did Alan Turing, or any of the mathematicians in his team, have anything to do with Ultra? Exactly who were the people (besides Menzies) involved in the development of Ultra?

Comment: This is asking several things the title differs from the main question

Comment: @Mark I don't think so. If you expand a little I can edit to make it clearer.

Comment: From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra#CITEREFWest1986) and its cites and other books I have read Ultra is the codeword for any intellignce from Enigma decryption - so no statistical stuff here - that was just to break the code. Also Wiki says Ultra codeword was named by Geoffrey Colpoys

Comment: @Mark [I read](http://www.ew.com/article/2014/11/28/fact-checking-the-film-imitation-game) that Menzies did use some sort of statistical analysis (I don't know how sophisticated) to determine which decrypted messages to act upon. This was part of Ultra, but maybe Ultra was bigger than that?

Comment: I would look at the books in the wikipedia article rather than current journalists

Comment: @Mark I agree. That's the point of asking this question in this site, to find veritable references explaining what things really are.

Comment: It all started with the Poles who developed a machine called the bombe (or bomba) that could decrypt enigma messages given a correct set of keys. Turing and friends figured out how to guess the encryption keys more efficiently due to a bug in the enigma (not sure if Turing himself figured out the bug but he did invent the sheet method). Turing then invented what is essentially a large parallel bombe that can be used to try out large numbers of keys on a message at once. Then he invented what's essentially a computer to automatically control the parallel bombes.

Comment: If you're interested in a less fictionalized version of at least some of the events that took place see this series of videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2NWPG2gB_A&list=PLSZR1tkzeKC1kzIHSGLmtlYwNaFoaMSV3